# Most efficient and practical way to store time values (HH:MM) in Oracle that makes it easily searchable

Tags: oracle

I have a set of starting and ending times that I need to store in an Oracle database.  I need to store them in a manner that makes them easily searchable (i.e. a typical search is find all rows where a time value, such as 9:30AM, falls in between the start time and end time).  In SQL Server I would just use a TIME datatype field, but Oracle does not appear to have an equivalent.

I have seen a number of blogs and forums that recommend just using a DATE field and doing conversions with TO_CHAR then comparing, or to store the time values as varchar(4 / HHMM) or varchar(6 / HHMMSS) fields.  Both of these seem needlessly inefficient.

Is there a better or more efficient way to accomplish this in Oracle?

Comment: I've never used this, but maybe it will help? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1006272

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you've no need to store the date component, then an `interval day(0) to second` is the most practical approach. The biggest advantage comes if you need to do any calculations finding how long has elapsed between two times as you don't need to do any extra processing out of the box.

For example:

```
create table times ( t1 interval day(0) to second, t2 interval day(0) to second);

insert into times values ( interval '0 09:30:00' day(0) to second, interval '0 12:30:00' day(0) to second);
insert into times values ( interval '0 10:30:00' day(0) to second, interval '0 13:45:00' day(0) to second);
insert into times values ( interval '0 11:30:00' day(0) to second, interval '0 12:05:01' day(0) to second);

commit;

SELECT * FROM times
where  t1 between interval '0 10:00:00' day to second and interval '0 11:00:00' day to second ;

T1          T2        
----------- -----------
0 10:30:0   0 13:45:0   

SELECT max(t2-t1) FROM times; 

MAX(T2-T1)
-----------
0 3:15:0.0
```

You also have standard functions to extract the various components of the time (hour, minute, etc.):

```
SELECT extract(hour from t1) hr, extract(minute from t1) mn, extract(second from t1) sec
FROM times; 

        HR         MN        SEC
---------- ---------- ----------
         9         30          0 
        10         30          0 
        11         30          0
```

Comment: Nice answer. I have found the INTERVAL datatype excellent for recording start and end times for recurring things like the hours an employee works every Monday. Such a "shifts" table shouldn't have date information in it; to that end the INTERVAL data type suits very well.

Answer (score 0):

Try storing as number.  Worst case is 3 bytes for HHMM, and 4 for HHMMSS.  01:00 would take 1 byte.

Answer (score 0):

I did some testing using oracle 11g and got this:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Mon May 13 22:40:32 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

Sessie: 44,8525
Eventueel trace-bestand: c:\app\administrator\diag\rdbms\sm10\sm10\trace\sm10_ora_5748.trc

sys@SM10> set timing on;
sys@SM10> set autotrace off;
sys@SM10> drop table timing;

Table dropped.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.07
sys@SM10> create table timing ( hoursDate date , hoursText varchar2(5) , hoursNumber number(4) ) nologging;

Table created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
sys@SM10> insert into timing (select to_date(trunc(dbms_random.value(0,23)) || ':' || trunc(dbms_random.value(0,59)),'HH24:MI'),to_char(trunc(dbms_random.value(0,23)) || ':' || tru
nc(dbms_random.value(0,59)) ), trunc(dbms_random.value(0,23)) ||  trunc(dbms_random.value(0,59)) from all_objects );

72514 rows created.

Elapsed: 00:00:02.72
sys@SM10> commit;

Commit complete.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
sys@SM10> insert /*+ append */ into timing select * from timing;

72514 rows created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.03
sys@SM10> commit;

Commit complete.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
sys@SM10> insert /*+ append */ into timing select * from timing;

145028 rows created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.05
sys@SM10> commit;

Commit complete.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
sys@SM10> insert /*+ append */ into timing select * from timing;

290056 rows created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.08
sys@SM10> commit;

Commit complete.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
sys@SM10> insert /*+ append */ into timing select * from timing;

580112 rows created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.15
sys@SM10> commit;

Commit complete.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
sys@SM10> insert /*+ append */ into timing select * from timing;

1160224 rows created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.28
sys@SM10> commit;

Commit complete.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
sys@SM10> insert /*+ append */ into timing select * from timing;

2320448 rows created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.51
sys@SM10> commit;

Commit complete.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
sys@SM10> select count (*) from timing;

  COUNT(*)
----------
   4640896

1 row selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.15
sys@SM10> create index normal_hourdate on timing(hoursDate) nologging;

Index created.

Elapsed: 00:00:04.54
sys@SM10> create index normal_hourtext on timing(hoursText) nologging;

Index created.

Elapsed: 00:00:14.21
sys@SM10> create index normal_hournumber on timing(hoursNumber) nologging;

Index created.

Elapsed: 00:00:10.33
sys@SM10> analyze table timing compute statistics for table for all indexes for all indexed columns;

Table analyzed.

Elapsed: 00:00:31.40
sys@SM10> set autotrace traceonly;
sys@SM10> alter system flush buffer_cache;

System altered.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.02
sys@SM10> select        * from timing where hoursDate between to_date('12:00','HH24:MI') and to_date('13:00','HH24:MI') ;

201152 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:01.81

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3409064691

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |        |   196K|  2879K|  4084   (6)| 00:00:50 |
|*  1 |  FILTER            |        |       |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| TIMING |   196K|  2879K|  4084   (6)| 00:00:50 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(TO_DATE('12:00','HH24:MI')<=TO_DATE('13:00','HH24:MI'))
   2 - filter("HOURSDATE">=TO_DATE('12:00','HH24:MI') AND
              "HOURSDATE"<=TO_DATE('13:00','HH24:MI'))


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          1  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
      27682  consistent gets
      14311  physical reads
          0  redo size
    5421569  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
     147925  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
      13412  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          0  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
     201152  rows processed

sys@SM10> alter system flush buffer_cache;

System altered.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
sys@SM10> select        * from timing where to_date(hoursText,'HH24:MI') between to_date('12:00','HH24:MI') and to_date('13:00','HH24:MI') ;

207104 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:04.27

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3409064691

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |        | 11602 |   169K|  4148   (7)| 00:00:50 |
|*  1 |  FILTER            |        |       |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| TIMING | 11602 |   169K|  4148   (7)| 00:00:50 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(TO_DATE('12:00','HH24:MI')<=TO_DATE('13:00','HH24:MI'))
   2 - filter(TO_DATE("HOURSTEXT",'HH24:MI')>=TO_DATE('12:00','HH24:MI')
               AND TO_DATE("HOURSTEXT",'HH24:MI')<=TO_DATE('13:00','HH24:MI'))


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          1  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
      28078  consistent gets
      14311  physical reads
          0  redo size
    5667161  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
     152281  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
      13808  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          0  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
     207104  rows processed

sys@SM10> alter system flush buffer_cache;

System altered.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
sys@SM10> select        * from timing where hoursNumber between 1200 and 1300 ;

171968 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:01.38

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 4284679420

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |        |   135K|  1988K|  3940   (2)| 00:00:48 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| TIMING |   135K|  1988K|  3940   (2)| 00:00:48 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("HOURSNUMBER">=1200 AND "HOURSNUMBER"<=1300)


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          1  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
      25746  consistent gets
      14311  physical reads
          0  redo size
    4654857  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
     126519  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
      11466  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          0  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
     171968  rows processed
```

So i would go for the DATE or NUMBER if i can. It is faster and smaller. Just make sure you ignore the DAY part of your date, if you don't need.

Answer (score -1):

I was looking up on the same scenario of storing hh:mm (or hhmm) into an oracle column. I tried the above example (of loading data into timing table) and found that since we use random value generator it is storing data 12.0 instead of 12.00 in the hoursText column (which is varchar). Also I think the queries are not using indexes since we have functions defined on the column in the

```
select ... where to_date(hoursText) between ...
```

I think we do not need this conversion to to_date. Why not:

```
select  * from timing where hoursText between '12:0' and '13:00' ;
```

I think this query will use the index and return results fast.